# Passing data collection object from Jquery ajax Method to MVC Controller showing null object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm try to pass data object to MVC controller using JQuery method. While I'm click submit button it will create data object in JavaScript method. Data Object is not null in Ajax method. When we passing it to MVC controller it hit the method correctly but data object is showing null.

I tried single object as well, but it also showing null.

This is JQuery Ajax Method:

```
$(function () {
    $('.save-user').on('click', function () {

        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var SrcCountryId = $("#ExchangeRateSetUpHeader_SrcCountryId option:selected").val();
        var DestCountryId = $("#ExchangeRateSetUpHeader_DestCountryId option:selected").val();
        var SrcCurrencyId = $("#ExchangeRateSetUpHeader_SrcCurrencyId option:selected").val();
        var DestCurrencyId = $("#ExchangeRateSetUpHeader_DestCurrencyId option:selected").val();
        var Rate = $("#ExchangeRateSetUpHeader_Rate").val();
        var RemittanceSettlementId = tr.find("#RemittanceId").val();
        var CommPercentage = tr.find("#CommPercentage").val();
        var CommFixed = tr.find("#CommFixed").val();
        var SellRate = tr.find("#SellRate").val();
        var Id = tr.find("#ItemId").val();

        var ExchangeRateSetUp =
            {
                "Id": Id,
                "SrcCountryId": SrcCountryId,
                "DestCountryId": DestCountryId,
                "SrcCurrencyId": SrcCurrencyId,
                "DestCurrencyId": DestCurrencyId,
                "Rate": Rate,
                "RemittanceSettlementId": RemittanceSettlementId,
                "CommPercentage": CommPercentage,
                "CommFixed": CommFixed,
                "SellRate": SellRate
            };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ExchangeRateSetUp/Create/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(ExchangeRateSetUp),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        });
        });
```

This is my MVC COntroller Method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(ExchangeRateSetUp model)
{
   return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Please help me to Sortout this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: where are you calling create method from ajax call?

Comment: bottom of the script method i called as 'url: '/ExchangeRateSetUp/Create/'

Comment: can you show ExchangeRateSetUp model code?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data as `json` string, hence you need to accept it as string in `create` method.

Change `ExchangeRateSetUp` object to `String` parameter in create method and then covert `String` to `ExchangeRateSetUp` object :

```
public JsonResult Create(String model)
{
   //convert String model into ExchangeRateSetUp here

   return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened for me. the reason was the absence of { get; set; } in the c# class defined to accept model in controller.

Check whether your class ExchangeRateSetUp has { get; set; }  for the properties